# What is happening in a React component when you used #extend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is happening inside here from what I understand is that you're building out your own `render` method, which will render the html of the `h1`. This `render` method is called by `React.DOM` to figure out what to give to the virtual dom. The same goes for methods such as `componentDidMount` right? If you put in any of those lifecycle methods or `render`, React will call them accordingly to fit inside their code, but if create other functions, those will just be helper functions for you to render stuff with, right?

I guess I'm just trying to understand which part of the `Component` class is being used by `React.DOM` and which parts am I building. It seems weird that some methods are used to "configure" the component while others are used as helpers. What code inside the `Component` class is the `React.DOM` using? Is it like stuff to figure out the diffs on when to rerender stuff?

```
class Greeting extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's something to consider: ages ago in times long past, React and React-DOM were one in the same. React was targeted solely to webapps. So we could use `h1`, `div`, `span`, `img`, all of that using React only.

Now let me ask you this question. Let's say they wanted to take React, and make it so it could not only render to the DOM of a webpage, but also render the different components of a native mobile application? What would you do in that situation?

Obviously, all of those aforementioned HTML DOM elements, `h1`s etc etc, would be utterly useless! Android and iOS interiors do not know what any of those are whatsoever.

So the logical solution is to abstract that away. Instead of having those DOM nodes be an inherent part of React, instead make it so that React can render wherever and whatever!

You see, the React engine works pretty much the same in both React Native (mobile development), and standard web-based React with React-DOM. The lifecycle methods, the principles of design, the reconciliation, the entire engine is the same. Because React isn't about HTML or native applications, it's about a paradigm of data flow from application state into UI state.

---

So then, what is React-DOM doing with your component? Not a whole lot of anything, really. All of the diffing, data flow, etc etc are all handled by React.

What React-DOM does is it *knows how to render the data provided by a React element as a DOM node*. It knows how to update them, how to delete, them, all of that. You see, having all those abilities as part of the React core would not be ideal now, because React targets other platforms where those abilities are useless. And they would only bloat the package.

Answer (score 2):

The only method inside the class you 'have' to provide is the render. The other component lifecycle methods, as you mentioned, are called if provided when those lifecycle methods come into play. If you have no need to tap into those other lifecycle methods (component just returns some markup based on props provided to it) and your component doesn't need its own state then I would highly recommend just using stateless functional components. The docs provided by React team are good for explaining this -

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html

As far as the 'helper methods' you mentioned, yes you can define as many methods as you need in your class. It is very common to split up some of the more complex rendering logic into smaller easier to read functions for code readability.

Comment: Here is another link to their docs that helps explain the component lifecycle methods and when they get called as well- https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html